# table overflow-x css

Tags: html, css

Firefox, does not seem to display the table with scrolling correctly. Safari, and Chrome are both displaying as expected, where they add a scroll bar for overflow-x. Does anyone have any suggestions on getting Firefox to respond?

```
<tr>
<td  colspan="5" style="max-width:980px; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap; ">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have content in that nested table? Also, what version of Firefox & Chrome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sometimes happens that you cannot directly work on table cells (even though the specs say you should be able to do that). As a workaround, you can introduce an element that contains all of the contents of the cell and set properties on it, e.g.

```
<td  colspan="5"><div style="max-width:980px; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap; ">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  ...
</table></div>
</td>
```

This workaround seems to help on Firefox (and on IE).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you fix the table layout (starting with `table-layout: fixed;` on the table itself) then then cell will always size to its content and therefore never overflow.